# How can I get Gmail Chat to run in background on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone

For my iPhone, is there anyway to have gmail chat ping me, when a new chat occurs, and I am on another app?  Unlike Android or Blackberry, I am amazed that I have yet not found anything that works well on the iphone for chatting with friends.  Am I missing something here?  Or is this just one of the greatest overlooked features that my iPhone does not have.

And any solution offered can be either from the app store or cydia.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[Trillian for iPhone](http://www.trillian.im/learn/tour-iphone.html) works great for this.  Supports push notifications and multiple other IM networks besides Google Chat.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a rather large fan of [Beejive](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/beejiveim-with-push/id291720439?mt=8) (iTunes Link). Supports push notifications, e-mail notifications, and server side idling up to 7 days without re-opening the app.

The (admitted) downside, is that the iPhone/iPad versions are different, not one universal app. For example, the above link is the iPhone ipa, and [this](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/beejiveim-for-ipad/id372269251?mt=8) is the iPad iTunes link.

$10 each. But they don't get any better. High quality app, great feature set, no ads (go figure), highly recommended.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [eBuddy for iPhone](http://www.ebuddy.com/mobile.php); signup then add your google account. It works the way you like.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question, iOS 4 allows apps to run in the background, but that doesn't work the same way as on the desktops. Background running apps should use very low memory and will be purged as soon as enough apps need the memory in front of it. So what you really need is pushing chat notifications, which helps save your phone battery because it's less power intensive and handled by the system.

[Nimbuz](http://www.nimbuzz.com/en/iphone/download) is another great free option that also supports voice calling, many IMs, push (from experience I think it lasts between 24 hours and 3 days top), and used to work even with skype voice. now there's no third party client that works with skype at all as far as I know.

It is my current favorite and I've tried many options, tho I haven't tried Trillian nor Beejive.

[Fring](http://www.fring.com/download/iphone/) is the first one for iPhone and is still great as well. It features video calling (between 2 frings). I prefer Nimbuzz because of little details, such as fring doesn't show from which protocol the specific profile is in the list.

In the end, the app you choose will be the best one for your personal taste, as there are plenty of good options.